# Can't see properties in context menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx

> Hi folks, I added a resource file in my asp.net webforms website and
> now I want to see the properties to make it "Embedded Resource", but
> when I right-click on to the resource file, I don't see any
> 'Properties' Menu there.

I tried adding a new item and added an existing item from another project but still, I can't see this menu. Googled the whole day to overcome this issue but nothing yet.

> The requirement is to make this web application bilingual (English and
> Arabic). I am doing wrong or if there is any easiest way to achieve
> this, please guide me.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rFLRdH0
see the screenshot of my application

Comment: someone help me please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources for web based applications are not like desktop ones. When you add a resource, it is placed as a plane jane file in a folder called Resources. it works this way, since then a URL or web based mark-up can see + use + consume such resources.

However, if you use the project properties and don't use "settings" and do use a resource? (and not a add file or say icon????).

Then in most cases you can get at the resources this way:

```
        TextBox2.Text = Properties.Resources.String1;
```

However, to pull a image from resources, and shove say into a image control, then you have to do like this:

```
        ImageConverter MyConvert = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] ImageBytes = (byte[])MyConvert.ConvertTo(Properties.Resources.horses, typeof(byte[]));

        var base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageBytes);
        Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Data;
```

In above, the image was "horses"

Comment: This was so simple, thanks. I am accessing it as below

C#
---
 lblAccounts.Text = Resources.Language.Arabic.Accounts;

ASPX Page
-----------
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAccounts" Text="<%$Resources:Language.Arabic, ccounts %>"></asp:Label>

I have a dropdown in the menu to select language, how do I manage these labels when the user changes the language.